# JApplet will not launch JComponent in browsers, works in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, jcomponent

I have coded a game proto-type in Java during my spare-time. This game was merely for my educational purposes only. I have it working fine via a JNLP launch file on the web, as well as on my main machine, via a JFrame.

My main intention is to make this proto-type playable in web-browsers via the use of a JApplet. I have coded a class, called AppletPlayer.java. The intention of this class is to essentially serve as a launcher for my Game's main class. The AppletPlayer.java file is pretty much as follows:

```
public class AppletPlayer extends JApplet {
private Game myGame_; // This is my game's main class
private boolean started_ = false;

public void init() {}

public void start() {

    if (!started_) {
        started_ = true;
        myGame_ = new Game();
        this.setContentPane(myGame_);
        myGame_.start() // I set focusable, and enabled to 'true' in the Game's start method
        // My Game class has no init method. Just a start method that spawns a new thread, that the game runs in
    }
}
```

Now, the Game class itself extends JComponent, and implements Runnable, KeyListener, and FocusListener. If I launch AppletPlayer via Eclipse it works like a charm in its Applet Viewer. However, when I deploy to the web I see two things:

1. On a Windows XP machine the Applet loads, stays stuck on the main title screen, never receiving focus, hence never registering any type of user input.
2. On a Windows 7 Machine the Applet loads, I hear my game's music, but the Applet screen itself renders a plain white box and nothing else.

These issues occur in both IE and Firefox.

I have been perusing Google and StackOverFlow for awhile now, trying to dig up a solution but haven't had any luck. I am a bit unfamiliar with Applets, and was hoping for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at the Java console - it may give some useful output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that may be the reason: Swing is not thread-safe, so all changes on the GUI (with includes your `setContentPane`) should occur in the AWT event dispatch thread.  The `start()` method of an applet is not called on this thread.

Wrap all your GUI-related method calls in an `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)` call (or `invokeAndWait`, if you need some results, and `SwingUtilities` also has these methods, if you prefer) and look if you see some changes.

Comment: I decided to just neatly tie in a link page to my JNLP file. However, your answer was much appreciated, and led to me researching and learning a lot in regards to the dispatcher thread.